# Can't see all open windows in Activites/search (super) view

Tags: display-resolution, activities-overview

I'm using a triple monitor setup where one of the monitors is portrait.
This portrait monitor is causing issues when viewing the activity/search view as it appears to be using the vertical resolution of the portrait monitor across all of the monitors.

When setting all displays as landscape you can see all the windows (5 browsers)
[All landscape screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcYMH.jpg)

However, when one monitor is portrait, you can only see 4 windows.
[Two landscape and one portrait screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zE0r.jpg).
The 5th window can be see in the top right. Also you can see that the bottom for the lower windows is also missing

Is there any way around this issue as it's quite frustrating when trying to quickly find windows?

Thanks